# class Pname1 is public, should be declared in a file named Pname1

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public class Pname {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;

        int b = 20;

        System.out.println("a+b=" + (a + b));

        System.out.println("Hello World!");

    }

}

public class Pname1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

          private String myName = "sha";

          private String myHname = "pra";

          System.out.println("the adding together is=" + (myName + myHname));

   }
}

public class Pname2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Comment: and the question is.... ? ? ?

Comment: You can declare one public class per source file and the source file must be named exactly like the class: Pname in Pname.java, Pname1 in Pname1.java, Pname2 in Pname2.java, ...

Answer (score 2):

Create three different java files, `Pname.java`, `Pname1.java` and `Pname2.java` and place your corresponding `public` classes in these files. In java, one .java source code file can contain at most one `public` class.

Comment: That's a correct and accurate explanation. By the way, this question's a trifle.